# Diagnosing SQL Server crash

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, configuration

Sorry, I'm a complete noob in configuring SQL Server. My program consists of 2 parts: web frontend and SQL Server backend.

Periodically SQL Server fails to respond (network error) and takes a time to restart.

I want to know why. How to diagnose it? Thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "fails to respond". Do you mean queries from your web frontend time out, or SQL Server Management studio becomes unresponsive? If you can access SQL Server via Management Studio, maybe check out the Activity Monitor for the database that is unresponsive. It might point to locks or long running queries that are causing your issues.

Comment: Yes, when trying to connect via Management Studio it reports network error, so does ado.net on the front end. I want to know which query causes this issue or what is the reason of this?

Comment: Hmmm, then Activity Monitor is unlikely to be of any use. Is this a recent thing? Maybe revisit some of your recent code changes to make sure you aren't leaking connections or something like that. If it is repeatable, then maybe use SQL Profiler and then do whatever it is that causes the system to become unresponsive. If it is a recent issue, then I'd be looking through the change history of your source code repository to look for changes to database related code. Maybe it'll show a clue. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look in to the SQL log first and windows event log whether you see some useful message which could give us more insight in your problem.

Comment: "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query" - how to work out which query caused this? or, rather, get 10 queries before this happens?

Comment: This can be quite ticky, try to run the SQL profiler and run a trace on the server. Once the issue appears again look into the trace to see what was happening during that time on the server.